# merge pairs in scala to an array

Tags: arrays, scala, merge, reachability

Input:

```
dupName = (ERIC,KAREN)
(ERIC,JASON)
(ERIC,ANTHONY)
```

Expected output:

```
(ERIC,KAREN,JASONC,ANTHONY)
```

I use `dupName.reduce(_ + _._2)`, which always get an Error:

```
[error]found   : String
[error]  required: (String, String)
```

Answer (score 0):

A reduce is aggregating all values of `A` into a single value of `A`. or in your case, aggregating several `(String, String)` into a single `(String, String)`. or in function form this is a reduce function:

```
(concatenatedPair : (String, String), currentPair : (String, String) => (String, String))
```

If you'd like to do what you're trying to do try you need to map, like so:

```
val arr = List(("ERIC", "JASON"), ("ERIC", "ANTHONY"), ("ERIC", "KAREN"))
val newArr = arr.flatMap(x => List(x._1, x._2)).distinct
// newArr is now List(ERIC, JASON, ANTHONY, KAREN)
```

This is just an example, as there are probably more efficient ways to do this (example: put the strings into a `Set`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I got confused by Array and List.

Comment: I'm not really familier with RDD though.

Comment: This isn't an RDD (**R**esilient **D**istributed **D**ataset), RDDs are from apache spark. This is just a regular old flatMap.

Comment: OK. Still thanks to you. I will see more docs to know more about rdd.